# Convert table from events to calendar date structure

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which gives the contract start and end date like for every user like below:

| user | product | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | trial | 2022-01-30 | 2022-03-01 |
| A | paid | 2022-03-02 | 2023-03-02 |
| A | trial | 2023-03-03 | 2023-04-02 |
| B | trial | 2022-05-06 | 2022-06-05 |
| B | trial | 2022-06-06 | 2022-07-06 |
| B | paid | 2022-07-07 | 2023-07-07 |
| C | trial | 2022-11-21 | 2022-12-21 |
| C | paid | 2022-12-22 | 2023-12-22 |
| C | paid | 2023-12-23 | 2024-12-22 |

How do I change it into a table with calendar dates and subscription existing for every date for each user?

| Date | User | PRODUCT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-30 | A | trial |
| 2022-01-31 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-01 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-02 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-03 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-04 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-05 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-06 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-07 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-08 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-09 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-10 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-11 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-12 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-13 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-14 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-15 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-16 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-17 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-18 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-19 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-20 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-21 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-22 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-23 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-24 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-25 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-26 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-27 | A | trial |
| 2022-02-28 | A | trial |
| 2022-03-01 | A | trial |
| 2022-03-02 | A | paid |
| 2022-03-03 | A | paid |
| 2022-03-04 | A | paid |
| 2022-03-05 | A | paid |
| 2022-03-06 | A | paid |
| 2022-03-07 | A | paid |
| 2022-03-08 | A | paid |
| 2022-03-09 | A | paid |
| 2022-03-10 | A | paid |

I tried:

```
With dates as (

 SELECT
  *
  FROM 
    UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-10-01', '2030-09-30', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as date )

select b.date,
q.product,
q.user,



from
(
user,
product,
start_date,
end_date
from table1
)
q CROSS JOIN dates b 
   WHERE b.date BETWEEN q.start_date AND q.end_date
```

Comment: What is the result of the query you've tried, besides the syntax error I assume you get from the extra comma after (q.user,) ? I don't have bigQuery but the gist you've got is pretty standard for exploding date intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Use below simple approach

```
select date,  user, product, 
from your_table, 
unnest(generate_date_array(date(start_date), date(end_date))) as date
order by user, date
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a syntax error and a subquery structure issue. You can use this alternative query instead:

```
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT date
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-10-01', '2030-09-30', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as date
)
SELECT 
  dates.date,
  q.product,
  q.user
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      user, 
      product, 
      start_date, 
      end_date
    FROM 
      table1
  ) q 
  CROSS JOIN dates
WHERE 
  dates.date BETWEEN q.start_date AND q.end_date
ORDER BY 
  q.user, dates.date;
```